# Why do npm commands error in GitBash but not Powershell?

Tags: powershell, npm, git-bash

I'm not sure when this started, it worked fine for a while but now in GitBash I get a "No such file or directory" error on `node: line 8` when I use any npm command.

Gitbash

```sh
B MINGW64 ~
$ where npm
C:\Users\B\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm
C:\Users\B\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.cmd

B MINGW64 ~
$ which npm
/c/Users/B/AppData/Roaming/npm/npm

B MINGW64 ~
$ npm -v
C:\Users\B\AppData\Roaming\npm/node: line 8: C:\Users\B\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

In Powershell commands work normally

```sh
PS C:\Users\B> npm -v                                     
7.6.3
```

for reference this is `node.cmd` where the error is coming from

```sh
@ECHO off
GOTO start
:find_dp0
SET dp0=%~dp0
EXIT /b
:start
SETLOCAL
CALL :find_dp0
"%dp0%\node_modules\node\bin\node"   %*
```

Why is `npm` looking for a missing file/dir when using GitBash and not Powershell?

**Edit** - I accidentally found out that entering the `cmd` command in gitbash first allows it to work. I have no idea why.

```sh
B MINGW64 /
$ npm -v
C:\Users\B\AppData\Roaming\npm/node: line 8: C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: No such file or directory

B MINGW64 /
$ cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.985]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files\Git>npm -v
npm -v
7.6.3
```

Comment: It might be from having paths as ``\` , if you use `/` instead, it works across more systems easier.

Comment: @ninMonkey, you're saying you think I should edit the `node.cmd` to use `/` instead of `\`? It seems like an unusual solution if it does work, I'm not sure I want to be editing the internal files of npm itself.

Comment: I guess you can't put a backslash in single backticks? ``\``