# trouble with firebase-tools global npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, path, git-bash, firebase-tools

I am trying to install `firebase-tools` via npm globally on my system. I am running Windows 11 and I use Git Bash. After installing from Git Bash with the command `npm install -g firebase-tools` and seeing the installation happen, I use the command `firebase login` and receive the error `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm/node: line 8: C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: No such file or directory`. When I check for globally installed npm packages I see

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── firebase-tools@13.0.2
```

When I check my environment variables for `Path` I see `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm` on the list. If I open windows Powershell at `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm` and run the command `./firebase` it works.

What am I doing wrong? I seem to consistently have trouble with Path environment variables on global package installs. What can I do to get firebase running correctly in Git Bash and how can I prevent this problem with future global installs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67826579/why-do-npm-commands-error-in-gitbash-but-not-powershell This also works for me. What does the `cmd` command in Git Bash do? Why can the system find firebase this way but not in Git Bash?